# Persist ViewState on CallBack request

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, callback, viewstate

The problem is, i need to persist `ViewState` during a `CallBack` request.

I know that ASP.NET by default doesn't save the page state when the request is a `CallBack`.
So, i would need an alternative to make it work.

The ASP.NET application has a custom `PageStatePersister`, where it stores all the Page State (`ViewState`) to the `Session`. This way the `ViewState` isn't sent/retrieved to the client in any moment (although the hidden field still exists on the page, but without value). The `ViewState` doesn't have to be returned on the `CallBack` response, i just need to invoke somehow the mechanism that saves the `ViewState` on a normal `PostBack` request.

It would be something like:

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Set anything to the viewstate for accessing on a later postback
    ViewState["Anything"] = 1;

    if (Page.IsCallback)
    {
        //Persist the page state manualy (not needed on normal postback)
        InvokeAspNetStateSaver();
    }
    ...
}
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.

Here's the thing.

After some decompiling of the `Page` class (`System.Web.UI`), i found basically what ASP.NET does in the request handling including the state loading and saving. The following code is what ASP.NET does on the method `ProcessRequestMain`:

```
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin PreInit");
this.PerformPreInit();
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End PreInit");
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin Init");
this.InitRecursive((Control) null);
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End Init");
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin InitComplete");
this.OnInitComplete(EventArgs.Empty);
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End InitComplete");

if (this.IsPostBack)
{
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin LoadState");
    this.LoadAllState();
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End LoadState");
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin ProcessPostData");
    this.ProcessPostData(this._requestValueCollection, true);
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End ProcessPostData");  
}

this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin PreLoad");
this.OnPreLoad(EventArgs.Empty);
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End PreLoad");
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin Load");
this.LoadRecursive();
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End Load");

if (this.IsPostBack)
{
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin ProcessPostData Second Try");
    this.ProcessPostData(this._leftoverPostData, false);
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End ProcessPostData Second Try");
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin Raise ChangedEvents");
    this.RaiseChangedEvents();
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End Raise ChangedEvents");
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin Raise PostBackEvent");
    this.RaisePostBackEvent(this._requestValueCollection);
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End Raise PostBackEvent");
}

this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin LoadComplete");
this.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs.Empty);
this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End LoadComplete");

if (this.IsPostBack && this.IsCallback)
    this.PrepareCallback(callbackControlID);
else if (!this.IsCrossPagePostBack)
{
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin PreRender");
    this.PreRenderRecursiveInternal();
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End PreRender");
}

...

if (this.IsCallback)
{
    this.RenderCallback();
}
else
{
    if (this.IsCrossPagePostBack)
        return;

    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin PreRenderComplete");
    this.PerformPreRenderComplete();
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End PreRenderComplete");
    this.BuildPageProfileTree(this.EnableViewState);
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin SaveState");
    this.SaveAllState();
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End SaveState");
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin SaveStateComplete");
    this.OnSaveStateComplete(EventArgs.Empty);
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End SaveStateComplete");
    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "Begin Render");

    if (exportedWebPartID != null)
        this.ExportWebPart(exportedWebPartID);
    else
        this.RenderControl(this.CreateHtmlTextWriter(this.Response.Output));

    this.Trace.Write("aspx.page", "End Render");
    this.CheckRemainingAsyncTasks(false);
}
```

The Method `LoadAllState()` is the responsible for loading the page state, it executes every PostBack request.

The Method `SaveAllState()` is the responsible for saving the page state. ASP.NET executes it like the following code:

```
if (this.IsCallback)
{
    this.RenderCallback();
}
else
{
    ...
    this.SaveAllState();
    ...
}
```

So that is the reason my `ViewState` does not get saved on a `CallBack` request!

So, finally, the solution! Call manually the `SaveAllState()` method using reflection!

```
if (Page.IsCallback)
{
    System.Reflection.MethodInfo saveAllStateMethod = typeof(System.Web.UI.Page).GetMethod("SaveAllState", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    saveAllStateMethod.Invoke(Page, null);
}
```

Comment: It's a bit a hack. Better use a **Session** or a full **PostBack**. Such hacks can be costly later, when code need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

View sate could be saved and loaded in SaveState and LoadState events on page. Since you have common base class for pages, where you want to save state, you can do something like:

```
    protected override object SaveViewState()
    {
        object state = base.SaveViewState();

        // your custom save logic
    }

    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        object state = // load your view state here
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);
    }
```

Different questios is, wether it is good design to store state somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The .NET Framework does not save the state when it is a callback request. So, the SaveViewState method will not be called (only when it is a normal postback). It should be some way to invoke the .NET Framework method that saves it. I just don't know where it is exactly.

Comment: Maybe you can call SaveViewState method manually, at some point in pages lifecycle on your callback request.